# Backbone bootstrapped collection doesn't initialize correctly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have an issue, that was really hard to notice, because for the most part everything works. It was only when I tried to manipulate my data in my collections initialize function that I found a problem.

The backbone docs at http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor

"If you define an initialize function, it will be invoked when the collection is created."

so I interpreted that as, my initialize function won't run until after my models are set. "That sounds ideal," said I, but then I ran into this.

My bootstrap code is as follows:

```
new MyCollection(<?php if ($data) {echo json_encode($data);} ?>);
```

My collection:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,

    initialize: function() { 
        console.log(this); 
        console.log(this.length);
        this.each(function(model) {
            console.log(model);
        });
    } 
});
```

I got strange results.

The first `console.log(this);` was a collection object as expected:

```
{ 
    .... 
    models: [3], 
    length: 3 
    .... 
}
```

and the second `console(this.length);` printed out the number `0`

the console inside `this.each()` didn't show up.

What's happening?

Comment: new MyCollection(<?php if ($data) {echo json_encode($data);} ?>); <- yuck

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Collection constructor [looks like this](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L597):

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection = function(models, options) {
  //...
  this._reset();
  this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  //...
  this.reset(models, {silent: true, parse: options.parse});
  //...
};
```

Step by step:

1. The [`this._reset()`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L896) call does a `this.length = 0`.
2. The `this.initialize.apply(...)` is the call to your `initialize` method.
3. The [`this.reset(...)`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L741) will call [`add`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L633) to add the models. The `add` call will update the collection's `models` and `length` properties.

So, when `initialize` is called, you'll have `this.length == 0` and `this.models` will be an empty array since only `_reset` will have been called here. Now we can easily see why `this.each` doesn't do anything and why `console.log(this.length)` says `0`.

But why does `console.log(this)` tell us that we have a populated collection? Well, `console.log` doesn't happen right away, it just grabs references to its arguments and logs something to the console a little bit later; by the time `console.log` gets around to putting something in the console, you'll have gotten through **(3)** above and that means that you'll have the `this.models` and `this.length` that you're expecting to see. If you say

```
console.log(this.toJSON());
```

or:

```
console.log(_(this.models).clone())
```

you'll see the state of things when `console.log` is called rather than the state of things when `console.log` writes to the console.

The documentation isn't exactly explicit about what is supposed to be ready when `initialize` is called so you're stuck tracing through the source. This isn't ideal but at least the Backbone source is clean and straight forward.

You'll notice that `initialize` is called like this:

```
this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
```

The [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) in there means that `initialize` will receive the same arguments as the constructor so you could look in there if you wanted:

```
initialize: function(models, options) {
    // The raw model data will be in `models` so do what
    // needs to be done.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough explanation. Now I see `reset` is called after my initialize and that explains why this is happening, but I still need to know how to access my models. Do I need to listen for a "reset" event before I can access things in the `each` call? `this.on("reset", this.doSomeStuff);`

Comment: Your edit cleared it up. Thank you very much. Although, I still don't think the console within `this.each()` will work correctly. I'll have to do `_.each(models, function(model) { // ... });`

Comment: @eO_Ae: Right, `this.collection.each` still won't do anything because that's just a wrapper for `_(this.collection.models).each(...)`. Note that `model` in your `_(models).each(...)` won't be a model object yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are bootstrapping incorrectly. You will need to use the Collection reset() method, and listen for a reset event in your collecton like so

Bootstrap code:

```
var collection = new MyCollection;
collection.reset(<?php if ($data) { echo json_encode($data); } ?>);
```

Your collection code:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,

    initialize: function() {
        this.on("reset", this.foobar);
    },

    foobar: function(collection) {
       console.log(this); // will be the same
       console.log(this.length); //  will equal 3
       this.each(function(model) {
           console.log(model); // will output a console for each model.
       });
    }

});
```

Comment: this helped a lot, and I see that this is the recommended way of bootstrapping according to the backbone FAQ.  http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap