# Backbone - adding an entry into the collection (From inside the collection)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a CollectionView that generates this kind of list

```
<ul>
    <li> All </li>
    <li> Option 2</li>
    <li> Option 2<li>
<ul>
```

All the Information about the second and third entry of this list is fetched from a DB. 
But I'd like to have the "All" option there as well. And I would like this option to be at the first position in my collection.

Only thing that came to my mind is to overwrite the MyCollection's `add()` method. It works pretty well, but I'm just checking if there isn't a better/simpler way to do it.

**MyCollection:**

```
define([ 'underscore',  'backbone', 'models/MyModel'], function(_, Backbone, MyModel){
  var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,

    initialize: function(opts) {
        this.options = opts;
        this.add({name: "All", icon_class="all"}) /// this doesn't work
    },

    add: function(models, options) {
      models.unshift({name:"All", icon_class:"all"})
      return this.set(models, _.extend({merge: false}, this.options));
    },
  });

  return MyCollection;
});
```

*( On a side note, the collection itself is not fetching the data from DB. The fetch is actually called form a (let's call it a) `ModelX` , which distributes the data to other collection that also make use of the same data.
So once the `ModelX` finishes fetching all the data, it passes the data to all the required views.)*

Comment: I would most likely have the view add that first element during rendering and keep it out of the collection entirely.

Comment: so I take it that it's not a good idea to add it from inside the collection , right?

Comment: That's my opinion on it at least. It's not so much that you're adding it from inside the collection but that you're adding it to the collection at all. It means your collection no longer represents the actual data from the server and that can come back and haunt you later.

Comment: I think this is the best option, considering that there is no need to make any major changes in my code. I just added an extra line which adds the additional entry while initializing my `CollectionView`...Though I'm not sure if I can mark your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm solving such problems on templating level. Because that element isn't really in your collection I wouldn't fake it:

```
<ul>
  <li>All</li>
  <% _.each(item, function (i) { %>
  <li><%- i.name%></li>
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah this would work if the list wasn't fully generated by Marionete's  `CollectionView`.I only need to provide the `CollectionView` with a colection object and a template which will be applied to each entry of my list.

Comment: Then I would add it right before the rendering to keep my collection identical to the server data as long as I can. I haven't used Marionette but it's sad when a library prevents you from implementing KISS solutions.

Comment: Use the Marionette `CompositeView` then?

Comment: actually it's not the Marionette, it's in fact the design of my app that is not letting me to do it. I would need to do quite a lot of changes to make it all work this way. I'd rather not do any major changes, unless there is no other way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea. Since you have separate models to represent the persistent data on the server, the data is this collection is clearly meant to represent view data, and so it's fine to put the *All* into the collection.

You could do it from within the collection or from an external "controller", depending on your architecture. You seem to want to do the former.

Your `add` hack is quite ugly, though. It would be much cleaner to override the constructor. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540237/2395796) for why doing it from `initialize` didn't work.)

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,

    constructor: function(models, options) {
        if (!models) models = [];

        models.unshift({name:"All", icon_class:"all"});
        Backbone.Collection.prototype.constructor.call(this, models, options);
    },
}
```